# JavaScript JSON. Any more efficient method

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to know if there is a more efficient way of typing this code.

```
view =  + data.items[ 0 ].statistics.viewCount
view1 =  + data.items[ 1 ].statistics.viewCount
view2 =  + data.items[ 2 ].statistics.viewCount
document.getElementById("views").innerHTML = view;
document.getElementById("views2").innerHTML = view1;
document.getElementById("views3").innerHTML = view2;
```

Comment: What makes you think this code is slow ?

Comment: Nothing would there be a better way. Getting more data with one line of code. I was thinking  data.items[0],[1],[2].statistics.viewCount

Comment: Don't know. But there are much more efficient ways to ask questions here on SO

Comment: OK so it's not about efficiency, but concision. Please edit you question to make this clearer. Also, since this actually has nothing to do with JSON, can you please remove the json tag?

Answer (score 0):

using jquery with an attribute starts with selector

```js
var viewCountArr = data.items.map(function(item) {
  return item.statistics.viewCount;
});

var elements = $('[id^="views"]');

$.each(elements, function(index, value) {
  $(this).html(viewCountArr[index]);
});
```

Comment: How is jQuery going to make things faster than natively written JS?

Comment: Thanks. Ill give it a go.

Comment: I assumed this was more so along the lines of the issue of having to type everything out manually not the speed

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version with slightly less repetition:

```
["views","views2","views3"].forEach(function(id, index){
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = data.items[index].statistics.viewCount;
});
```

Note that the `.forEach` method call assumes ES5 or higher; if you're targeting ES3, you may want to use something like Underscore's `_.each`, or whatever your current libraries provide.

Answer (score -1):

assuming your data is something like

```
var data = {
  items: [
    {statistics: {viewcount: 5}},
    {statistics: {viewcount: 346}},
    {statistics: {viewcount: 123}}
  ]
};
```

i would do

```
data.items.map(function(el, i){
  var idx = 'views' + (i > 0 ? i+1 : '');
  document.getElementById(idx).innerHTML = el.statistics.viewcount;
});
```

JSBin [here](https://jsbin.com/wiyodutuha/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Note that the first id is `view`, not `view1`.